# Dynamically adding wxPanel to sizer not refreshing pane

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

[image]I am trying to dynamically add and remove wxPanel's to a sizer depending on what item is clicked in a tree control, the pages are added, but when I add the panel the previous contents isn't erased cleared, I am using the following code:

```
void ManageProjectMain::SelectSubPageReleaseDetails()
{
    switch( m_activePage )
    {
    case ProjectMainSubPage_releaseDetails:
        break;

    case ProjectMainSubPage_cycleDetails:
        m_sizer->Detach( 0 ); 
        m_releaseCycleDetailsPane->Hide();
        m_sizer->Prepend( m_releaseDetailsPane, 1, wxGROW );
        m_releaseDetailsPane->Show();
        break;

    case ProjectMainSubPage_folderDetails:
        m_sizer->Detach( 0 ); 
        m_releaseFolderDetailsPane->Hide();
        m_sizer->Prepend( m_releaseDetailsPane, 1, wxGROW );
        m_releaseDetailsPane->Show();
        break;
    }

    m_activePage = ProjectMainSubPage_releaseDetails;
    m_sizer->Layout();
    m_releaseDetailsPane->Refresh();
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what exactly is wrong with this code, although detaching and inserting the pages is strange and shouldn't be necessary.

However you could be interested in replacing it entirely with [wxTreebook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_treebook.html) or, if you want to preserve the code building the tree, just [wxSimplebook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_simplebook.html) for the right hand side.

Comment: Unfortunately wxTreebook isn't what I envisioned my GUI to look like, thank you.  I am planning to now use that elsewhere in the project so thank you for that.   Are you saying that instead of attaching/reattaching I can just hide and unhide panels?

Comment: Strange, what you show looks _exactly_ like a `wxTreebook`. But yes, if you can't use it, you should just hide and show panels, the hidden ones will be ignored by the sizer for the layout purposes (and this is exactly what `wxSimplebook` class does, you can look at its [entire implementation](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/simplebook.h) to see how it works).